# Need code to perform binary search tree with graphics on java - insertion and deletion

Tags: java, swing, graphics, binary-search-tree, jcomponent

I need to perform binary search tree operations - insert, delete, search on java with graphics.
The UI must look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4yyU.png

I've written the code for insertion and have made the UI. But I feel the code I've written is quite primitive and also read that this would be easier if I used Buffered Images and I tried that but am unable to implement it.

I'm also having trouble with the delete function - removing the nodes and repainting the tree. Some sample code for the delete function sure would help me a lot.

So any help with the delete function and making the insertion code easier to work with is much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WithUI extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel p1,p2,p3;
    JTextField ins,del,find;
    JButton ins_but,del_but,find_but,print_but;
    JLabel bst_heading;

    //DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
    String p = " ";
    int mov1 = 0;
    int mov2 = 0;


    class Node{
        Node left = null;
        Node right = null;
        int value;

        Node(int val){
            this.value = val;
        }
    }

    WithUI(){

        //Creating UI
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        ins = new JTextField(7);
        del = new JTextField(7);
        find = new JTextField(7);
        ins_but = new JButton("Insert");
        del_but = new JButton("Delete");
        find_but = new JButton("Find");
        print_but = new JButton("Print");
        bst_heading = new JLabel("Binary Search Tree");
        Font f1 = new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,70);
        bst_heading.setFont(f1);
        bst_heading.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        p1.setBackground(Color.green.darker().darker());
        p1.setBounds(0,0,800,100);
        p1.add(bst_heading);
        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        p2.add(ins); p2.add(ins_but);
        p2.add(del); p2.add(del_but);
        p2.add(find); p2.add(find_but);
        p2.add(print_but);
        p2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        p2.setBounds(0,100,800,50);
        p3.add(p1);
        p3.add(p2);
        p3.setBounds(0,0,800,150);
        add(p3);
        setLayout(null);
        //add(panel);
        setFocusable(true);

        //Creating main node

        Node nodeMain = new Node(15);
        nodeMain.left = null;
        nodeMain.right = null;
        JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(nodeMain.value)); // LABEL1
        add(mainLabel);
        mainLabel.setBackground(Color.green.darker().darker());
        mainLabel.setOpaque(true);
        mainLabel.setBounds(400,200,25,25);
        mainLabel.setForeground(Color.yellow);

        ins_but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int left = 400;
                int down = 200;
                int val = Integer.parseInt(ins.getText());

                JLabel label = new JLabel(ins.getText());
                label.setForeground(Color.yellow);
                String s = insertNode(val, nodeMain, left, down);
                String[] nums = s.split("\\s+");
                add(label);
                int[] numsInt = { 400, 200, 400, 200 };
                numsInt[0] = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
                numsInt[1] = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
                numsInt[2] = Integer.parseInt(nums[2]);
                numsInt[3] = Integer.parseInt(nums[3]);
                label.setBounds(numsInt[0], numsInt[1], 25, 25);
                label.setBackground(Color.green.darker().darker());
                label.setOpaque(true);
                Graphics g = getGraphics();
                g.drawLine(numsInt[2] + 25, numsInt[3] + 55, numsInt[0] + 20, numsInt[1] + 30); // messy part
                System.out.println(nums[2] + " " + nums[3] + "     " + nums[0] + " " + nums[1]);
                System.out.println(numsInt[0] + " " + numsInt[1] + " " + numsInt[2] + " " + numsInt[3] + " ");
                System.out.println();

            }

        });

    }


    /*public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green.darker().darker());
        g.drawOval(400, 200, 50, 50);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(num),450,250);
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new WithUI();
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    String insertNode(int value, Node nodeMain, int left, int down) {
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
        if (nodeMain.value > newNode.value && nodeMain.left != null) {
            if (left == 400 && down == 200)
                insertNode(newNode.value, nodeMain.left, left - 100, down + 60);
            else
                insertNode(newNode.value, nodeMain.left, left - 30, down + 30);
        }

        else if (nodeMain.value < newNode.value && nodeMain.right != null) {
            if (left == 400 && down == 200)
                insertNode(newNode.value, nodeMain.right, left + 100, down + 60);
            else
                insertNode(newNode.value, nodeMain.right, left + 30, down + 30);
        }

        else if (nodeMain.left == null && nodeMain.value > newNode.value) {
            nodeMain.left = newNode;

            if (left == 400 && down == 200)
                p = String.valueOf(left - 100) + " " + String.valueOf(down + 60) + " " + String.valueOf(left) + " "
                        + String.valueOf(down);
            else
                p = String.valueOf(left - 30) + " " + String.valueOf(down + 30) + " " + String.valueOf(left) + " "
                        + String.valueOf(down);
            return p;

        } else if (nodeMain.right == null && nodeMain.value < newNode.value) {
            nodeMain.right = newNode;

            if (left == 400 && down == 200)
                p = String.valueOf(left + 100) + " " + String.valueOf(down + 60) + " " + String.valueOf(left) + " "
                        + String.valueOf(down);

            else
                p = String.valueOf(left + 30) + " " + String.valueOf(down + 30) + " " + String.valueOf(left) + " "
                        + String.valueOf(down);
            return p;

        }
        return p;

    }
}
```